# Music database identifier (e.g. MBID) in EAC FLAC/Vorbis metadata

Tags: metadata, flac, vorbis, exact-audio-copy

**I want to …**

- … rip Audio CDs with FLAC output using Exact Audio Copy (EAC).
- … include an universally unique identifier for the exact release (specific label/year/country/etc.), additionally to common fields like artist, etc.
- … preferably use the MBID (MusicBrainz Identifier) for this cause, since MusicBrainz is free and quite complete.
- … add it via command line options, as EAC tags work: `-T⠀"VORBISCOMMENTFIELD=%eacplaceholder%"`
- … have this done on-the-fly during a single rip (i.e. no manual post-encoding lookup).

⠀

**My problems are that …**

- … the [EAC FAQ](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/en/index.php/support/faq/) lists some placeholders, but merely `%cddbid%` (freedb ID) in regards to this question.
- … I can’t quite find standardized Vorbis comment fields corresponding to music database identifiers (like `CATALOGID/CATALOGNUMBER` or concrete CDDB/freedb/etc. IDs).
- … though [MusicBrainz Picard maps](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/docs/mappings/) their [tag system](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/docs/tags/) rather nicely …
- … EAC seems to be the limiting factor, since it seemingly cannot convey fetched metadata arbitrarily to the encoder parameters.

⠀

**Does somebody know a solution to this?**

Or is this too specific and ought to be asked someplace particularly devoted to EAC?

Comment: While waiting and searching for a more comfortable solution, I have [MusicBrainz Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz_Picard) opened parallel to EAC and lookup releases with it.